# End all Docker processes

Tags: ubuntu, docker

On Ubuntu, I use Docker intermittently for software development involving packages not currently available through official channels. I'm on a low-spec system and I want to make Docker disappear from the task list when I'm done with it, including all containers, daemons, and Docker-related processes.

I am not running as root, I do not understand systemd, and I have had no luck with killall, docker stop, or docker kill. I don't want Docker starting again, I want it gone until the next time I ask for it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Stop all containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

Stop docker engine

```
[sudo] systemctl stop docker
```

Prevent the engine from being started on reboot:

```
[sudo] systemctl disable docker
```

This said, `dockerd` and `docker-containerd` are fairly small processes (`systemctl status docker` reports 65MB total)